# How can I create a 2-column layout where one column has a fixed width and the other column adapts its height to the content?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a 2-column layout where one column has a fixed width and the other column takes up the remaining width of the viewport. The content in the variable-width column can vary in height, and I want both columns to adapt their height to the content. If the content in the variable-width column is larger than the height of the viewport, the entire page should scroll to accommodate the content.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="fixed-width-column">
    <!-- content for fixed-width column -->
  </div>
  <div class="variable-width-column">
    <div class="sub-div-1">
      <!-- content for sub-div-1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="sub-div-2">
      <!-- content for sub-div-2 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fixed-width-column {
  width: 300px;
}

.variable-width-column {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sub-div-1 {
  height: 33%;
}

.sub-div-2 {
  height: 67%;
}
```

I'm running into an issue where when the content in the sub-div-2 is larger than the height of the viewport, it creates whitespace at the bottom instead of scrolling. I've tried various approaches, including using overflow-y: auto on the sub-div-2 and setting height: 100% on various elements, but nothing seems to work. I expected the page to scroll when the content exceeds the height of the viewport, but instead, it creates whitespace at the bottom.

I tried various approaches, including setting overflow-y: auto on the sub-div-2 and setting height: 100% on various elements. I expected the page to scroll when the content in the sub-div-2 exceeds the height of the viewport, but instead, it creates whitespace at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```css
#one {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#two {
  flex: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: limegreen;
}

#three {
  background: aqua;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

here, by not defining heights for the children elements, the elements will take the height of the parent. and by setting the overflow to scroll will give u scrollable element.

I hope this answers your question